# I need to calculate numbers from argv input, but the numbers aren't integers they are chars. How do i cast?

Tags: c

I cant calculate numbers that are not integers. i need a way to cast chars into strings to use atoi() function with, or at least a way to calculate these numbers

I tried subtracting 48/'0' from the char.

argv = ADD 2 3 5 7 11 13

```
#define MINIMUM_ARGS 2

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    int calc = 0;
    char string[2] = { 0 };
    if ((strcmp(argv[1], "SUB") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "ADD") == 0) && ((argc - MINIMUM_ARGS) > 1))
    {
        string[0] = argv[2];  //Making calc be the value of the first number.
        calc = atoi(string);
        for (i = 3; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[1], "SUB") == 0)
            {
                if (strlen(argv[i]) > MINIMUM_ARGS)
                {
                    calc -= atoi(argv[i]);
                }
                else
                {         
                    calc -= atoi(argv[i] - 48);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (strlen(argv[i]) < MINIMUM_ARGS)
                {
                    string[0] = argv[i];
                    calc += atoi(string);
                }
                else
                {
                    calc += atoi(argv[i]);
                }
            }

        }
        printf("Result: %d", calc);

    }
```

Expected = 41
Got = 0

Comment: `string[0] = argv[2];` You are assigning a `char *` to a `char`. Did you mean `string[0] = argv[2][0];`?

Comment: `calc = atoi(string);`--> `calc = atoi(argv[2]);` ?

Comment: You don't cast, you convert.

Comment: @4386427 you are right i meant ADD

Comment: You are making things more complicated than needed. Simply do `calc = atoi(argv[2]);
        for (i = 3; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[1], "SUB") == 0)
            {
              calc -= atoi(argv[i]);
            }
            else
            {
              calc += atoi(argv[i]);
            }

        }
`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are making things more complicated than needed. I don't understand why `MINIMUM_ARGS` is used in the code that converts the input strings to numbers - `atoi` is all you need.

Perhaps like:

```
#define MINIMUM_ARGS 3

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    int calc = 0;
    if ((strcmp(argv[1], "SUB") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "ADD") == 0) && (argc >= MINIMUM_ARGS))
    {
        calc = atoi(argv[2]);
        for (i = 3; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[1], "SUB") == 0)
            {
              calc -= atoi(argv[i]);
            }
            else
            {
              calc += atoi(argv[i]);
            }

        }
        printf("Result: %d\n", calc);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i got told atoi can only work on strings not chars.

Comment: @RonUchitel : You should learn how work strings in C language

Comment: @RonUchitel Well, I think you misunderstand what `argv[i]` is. It's not a char! It is a **pointer to a zero terminated char array**, i.e. it is a string.